# Formating dates style in LibreOffice Calc Formula

Tags: libreoffice-calc

**Original Question** 
I just editing a spreadsheet file using LibreOffice Calc 5.0.2.2 and entering formula in cell A1 `=MONTH(NOW())`. Obviously, it will print out in cell `A1`: as `11`, as the curent month is 11th Month, November.

What I want to ask is, if I want to use DATE formula as above (`=MONTH(NOW())`), but I want the output as `November` instead `11`, how do I do it?

**Addendum (Revised)**

- My problem is, I want to concatenante a String with a Date, so I Use:

   `=CONCATENATE("Printing Date: ", NOW())`, it will produce: 
   
  "Printing Date: 42319.3177" which should be `10-11-15` 
  *I had changed the cell type as Date, but it still gives decimal number behind.*
- Knowing this Issue and after searching in Stackexchange, then I use ( just example):

   `=CONCATENANTE("Printing Date: :,MONTH(NOW))`  this will produce:

   "Printed Date: 11" 
  *This remove the decimal number issue, but it give me the number of current month.*
- What I want to ask is, if I want to use the formula 
  `MONTH(NOW())`, but I want the output as `November`
  instead of `11`, how do I do it?
- So, I think changing the cell type into Date when we use combinated
  formula like above will not make any effect.

Are there any solution to this?

Many thanks in advance!

**NB:**

- To produce `"Printing Date: 10-11-15 10:20"` My formula is:
   `=CONCATENATE("Printing Date: ",DAY(NOW()),"-",MONTH(NOW()),"-",YEAR(NOW()),"
  ",HOUR(NOW()),":",MINUTE(NOW()))`

Answer (score 1):

Format the cell and change the formatting to the code (MMMM), and use only NOW() (rather than MONTH(NOW()))

[image: Dialog]

You say you want to prefix it with other text, how about this?

[image]

Comment: Yep, I had done that before, but it gave me decimal number, while changing the cell type to Date did not give me te expected result (still as decimal). In my case I use combinated formula with CONCATENANTE, I will edit my question above. : ) . Thx for ur reply.

Comment: @Idad check my edit, Format "Printing Date:" MM-DD-YY HH:MM:SS   for Printing Date: 10-11-15 10:20